# using date type with REGEXP in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to know if someone could please tell me why the first one does not work and the second one does? Thanks in advance :)

```
DECLARE
    fecha DATE:= TO_DATE('20/04/1996', 'DD/MM/YYYY'); 
BEGIN

    IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE(TO_CHAR(fecha), '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}') THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE IS NOT CORRECTLY');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE CORRECTLY');
    END IF;
END;


-------------------------

DECLARE
    fecha varchar2(10):= '20/04/1996';
BEGIN
    IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE(fecha, '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}') THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FECHA INGRESADA INCORRECTAMENTE');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FECHA INGRESADA CORRECTAMENTE');
    END IF;
END;
```

How should I write inside a trigger? i have doubt about `:NEW.date_start`, `should I put TO_CHAR(:NEW.fecha_ingreso)`?

```
 IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE(:NEW.date_start, '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}') THEN
          RAISE error_formato_fecha;
      END IF;
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to validate a date. If it's in a date datatype then Oracle has already done this validation for you (it's a date) and you do not need to do any validation to check that it's a date. If you're looking to validate a date before converting it to a date then it should already be a character and you don't need to perform the conversion to a character.

Comment: @Ben But what happens if the user enters a date so dd / mm / yy, but I need it so dd / mm / yyyy so I thought to create the trigger to save an error and indicate that the format of the date is incorrect. Or is it wrong?

Comment: It's  not wrong if you're doing days validation, however your code is passing a date in which means your data validation has already been done. If your not going to perform a transformation from a character to a date in your trigger then there's no point in having the trigger...